# What's the point of Xaxos' power in Aeon's end?

Tags: aeons-end

I've started playing Aeon's end lately, and on the base set there's one Mage that seems hardly fair, but somehow he ends up way too strong or way too weak, depending at how one interpret his power.

The power is written this way :

> Metaphysical Link (5 charges): Activate during any player's main
>   phase: Allies collectively gain 4 charges. Reveal the turn order deck
>   and return the revealed cards in any order

At first we tought it shuffled the turn orders with it , hence it allows a "semi" infinite loop since it would be almost self-sufficientand allowed you to chain ally turns until the monster is beaten.

Then, we thought this was too powerful to be left, as is, it must be only the turn orders not played this turn. Thus, the power is near useless since it needs you to play first or so in order for it to be somehow effective, otherwise you could have only the nemesis' turns left in the draw, or some of them + 1/2 ally. I hardly find this worthwhile especially since the power costs so much. The "give energy to the team" thing is quite good, but if you got spells or gems that give charges for free, it would be easier and more flexible to use it directly.

So I'm quite confused. Is this power supposed to be terribly effective ? Is this power supposed to be lackluster? In which situation would Xaxos be a good pick ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Context, Cost, and Timing are the definition of Xaxos power**

Xaxos power is amazing: its ability to manipulate the turn order deck can save the game from being lost or set up some really amazing combos, it is one of the 'cheapest' powers in the game, and it can be extremely useful when combined with certain other mages.

Lets look at each part of his power:

1. Cost of 5: this is pretty much normal, and powers that only cost 4 are usually weaker than the ones that cost 5+.
2. Activate during any player's main phase: You don't have to activate this on your turn which means it doesn't matter who goes first in a round, you can immediately set up the entire round to go the way you want it to go. More on this in a minute but since a lot of powers are restricted to your own main phase, this definitely gives this power an advantage.
3. Allies collectively gain 4 charges: This effectively refunds almost the entire cost of your ability to your team, making this one of the most efficient powers in the game. While there are a lot of cards and abilities that grant charges to 'yourself or an ally',  granting that charge to an ally means you don't get to use your own power as often. Not so if you're granting that charge to Xaxos, since he refunds those charges back to the other players when his ability triggers. In most games I play with him, the Xaxos rarely generates more than 1 charge for himself but he still ends every round with full charges, refunding them to the rest of the team at the start of the following round.
4. Reveal the turn order deck and return the revealed cards in any order: This can be used in two ways: control the nemesis turns or set up player combos (or both). Controlling exactly when the nemesis turns trigger can allow your team to knock out a critical bad guy before he destroys someone, or it can allow you to set up a teammate with just the right discard trigger to get rid of a nasty power card before it goes off, or even just break up the nemesis turns so he doesn't go back-to-back and toss out (and immediately trigger) a strong Power 1 card with no chance for your team to respond to it. Setting up player combos can also be very powerful and there's too many combos for me to list them all (e.g. letting the mage who just prepped a full load of powerful spells go before the nemesis forces everyone to discard prepped spells), but Xaxos' own unique starting spell benefits from this too by allowing you to set up a Player turn order card immediately after your own and amp up the power of your spell.

There are probably a ton of other examples of how this is useful, but to me Xaxos is definitely a strong contender for a position at the table in almost any game of Aeon's End I play.

Comment: I totally overlooked it's usable in every player phase and not only his. This way, it's much better, thanks !! =)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how you consider this a lackluster power but it is one that can be very powerful when used carefully.

The main purpose of this power is for when Xaxos has a turn earlier in the sequence and can use this ability not only help complete the charges of several allies abilities but to ensure that they have the ability to use them in the correct sequence.

The ability to completely alter the turn order to ensure it is as advantageous to you as possible is where the power comes from.

As for your complaint about needing to play first that is something that is an issue with everything in the game and I have personally lost plenty of games because the turn order did not go as needed.

Comment: I compare it to the other "base" mages there is. Jain's power cost less, is more flexible (on your turn if you've got it charged you can unleash it with any spell available. Be it prepared on this turn or previously), The draw 4 card power is also easier to unleash and as flexible. The healing power isn't that powerfull but always useful since it's the only "heal" that is not a spell in the base game. All in all, Xaxos power seems to be good, when stars are aligned. The game does not seem to insure this can even happend everygame, that's why I said lackluster

Comment: Also the fact that it's not alter totally the turn order, it's only what's remaining that's altered. Thanks for your answer anyway